# javascript program verifies username w/ eight characters, one numeric and beginning with a letter. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Verify username has eight characters, contains a letter in the first part and 
// at least one number

// Declare variables and constants
var username;           // username entered by user
var charAny;            // text character identified in username
var anyNum = false;     // digit variable used to detect whether the username has one or not
var index;              // index loop variable
var BR = "<br />";      //break
var ES = "";            //space

// Display program requirements for the username requested
document.write("We'll begin helping you select a username" + BR);
document.write("Your username must have at least 8 characters," + BR);
document.write("   start with a letter, and contain at least 1 numeric character." + BR);
username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);

// Check for length of username
while (username.length < 8) {
    document.write("Your username must be at least 8 characters long." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
}

// Check that first character is a letter
// Substring function has three arguments: string, starting position, and ending position
charAny = username.substr(0, 1);
while (charAny !== isLetter()) {
    document.write("The first character of your username must be a letter." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
}

// Check that there's at least one digit in the username
while (anyNum !== false) {
// Check each character, set anyNum to true if a digit
    for (index = 1; index < username.substr(index, index); index++) {
        anyNum = username.substr(index, index);
        if (isNumeric(charAny)) {
            anyNum = true;
        }
    }

    // If anyNum is false there were no numerics
    if (anyNum !== true) {
        document.write("Your username must include at least 1 digit." + BR);
        username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
    }
}

// Thank the user and end the program
document.write("Thank you! Your new username is: " + username);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the username still verifies as long as there are eight characters, even when there is no numeric present. What am I doing wrong that it skips verifying numeric?
I've made edits to make sure that the variables are correct

Comment: You set `char1` but check `charAny` ...

Comment: I just changed it to be the proper variable but it's still skipping verifying if there is a numeric when I type an 8 character password.

Comment: Your for loop should say `for(var index=1;index<username.length;index++)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to test your code, since `document.write` is disallowed in JSFiddle. In general you don't want to use `document.write` anyway. Another tip, you can treat Javascript strings as arrays.

Here is a sample function that does what you're asking.

```
function checkUsername(test){
    var good = true;
    if (!test[0].match(/[a-z]/i)) good = false; // first character is not a letter
    if (test.length < 8) good = false; // less than 8 characters
    if (test.match(/\d+/g) == null) good = false; //contains no numbers
    return good;
}
```

Comment: I have to use the substring and isLetter() and isNumeric() validation unfortunately

Comment: ...but isLetter() isn't a function in Javascript.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with my textbook. For the problem at hand it specifically states that we can use the functions substring(), isLetter() and isNumeric() to validate.

Comment: Name of your textbook? isNumeric() and isLetter() are very popular functions in Java. Not Javascript. It's possible that the textbook is asking you to write your own functions for these purposes.

Comment: Principles of Program Design - Problem Solving with JavaScript by Paul Addison.

Comment: So I was looking through the book and it honestly seems like it is Visual Basic or a similar language: http://books.google.com/books?id=qRIJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA342&lpg=PA347&ots=JO6AVcgYck&focus=viewport&dq=Principles+of+Program+Design+-+Problem+Solving+with+JavaScript++isnumeric&output=html_text

Comment: That last seven weeks or so. Our tech dept. at school has a problem with textbooks. Even our Dreamweaver CS6 book is messed up with the projects. I wouldn't be surprised if it was an error but the teacher says it can be done...we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

If the username contains all non digit, anyNum is never set to true.
In the Check Each Character loop you assign a substring of username to the anyNum variable. So if the username consists of all non digits, the variable will never have a boolean (true/false) value.

Furthermore I have the folllowing remarks/findings:

- Check Each character loop: assign the substring to charAny and not to anyNum.
- Check Each character loop: assign 1 character to charAny username.substr(index, 1).
- Check Each character loop: check in the while clause on username.length.
- use for the ceck of the first character if instead of while
- General: you can also use a regular expression to check the format of the username (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I'm trying to use your advice but still nothing

Comment: Do you have an example of code I can look at? This is super bugging me (no pun intended).

Comment: You have declared anyNum = false at the start of the document. It will never go in the while loop to check the username.

Comment: Check my most recent answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to go ahead and delete this and scrap the way I started the code. There's obviously more efficient ways than re-creating the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Verify username has eight characters, contains a letter in the first part and 
// at least one number

// Declare variables and constants
var username;           // username entered by user
var anyNum = false;     // digit variable used to detect whether the username has one or not
var index;              // index loop variable
var BR = "<br />";      //break
var ES = "";            //space

// Display program requirements for the username requested
//document.write("We'll begin helping you select a username" + BR);
//document.write("Your username must have at least 8 characters," + BR);
//document.write("   start with a letter, and contain at least 1 numeric character." + BR);
username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);

// Check for length of username
if (username.length < 8) {
    document.write("Your username must be at least 8 characters long." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
}

// Check that first character is a letter
// Substring function has three arguments: string, starting position, and ending position

charAny = username.substr(0, 1);
if (!isLetter(charAny)) {
    document.write("The first character of your username must be a letter." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
}

// Check each character, set anyNum to true if a digit
    for (index = 1; index < username.length; index++) {
        charAny = username.substr(index, 1);
        if (isNumeric(charAny)) {
            anyNum = true;
        }
    }

    // If anyNum is false there were no numerics
    if (anyNum !== true) {
        document.write("Your username must include at least 1 digit." + BR);
        username = prompt("Please enter your username: ", ES);
    }

// Thank the user and end the program
document.write("Thank you! Your new username is: " + username);

function isLetter(character) {
return true;
}

function isNumeric(character) {
return ("01234567890".search(character) > -1);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must write the functions for isNumeric and isLetter.

Answer (score 0):

I was instructed to approach the problem as such:

var char1 = myPassword.substr(0,1);
 if(isNaN(char1) == true)
 isFirstLetterACharacter would be a boolean variable that you personally assign, and then set as a flag for the loop to end.

This is what my pseudocode would look like. Notice I kind of brute forced the thing.  I don't have to check every character on a sixteen character password, just the first 8 will suffice.

function passwordChecker(pass1)
 {

two conditions must be met for the loop to end:  first letter is a character must be true AND at least one letter starting at character two is numeric must also be true.

inside that while loop:

if pass1.length is greater than or equal to 8

make eight characters, char 1 through char8.

if char1 is not a number, then firstletterisacharacter is true.  else, tell the user so.

if char2 is a number (the opposite of not a number), then at least one letter starting at character two is numeric will be true.

ask the same question over and over again for chars 3 through 8.

all else, say the password is not long enough.